# Setting props when defining a new instance of a class

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create an invoice application using typescript. I created an Invoice class that has three objects as properties and within those objects they have their respective props. For testing purposes, in the constructor, I've only passed in the props from the item object. I want to create an instance of the invoice class and have the props of the item object (within the invoice class) be set from `<input>` the value of input tags. When I was testing just to see if the instance of the object was created, I keep getting this error:

Cannot set property 'price' of undefined at new Invoice

Here is my code

```
// invoice class
class Invoice {
    // fields
    item: {
        price: number;
        partNumber: number;
        partDescription: string;
        quantity: number;
        pricePerItem: number;
        discountApplied: number;
    }

    invoiceState: {
        valid: {
            OK: boolean;
            NOTOK: boolean;
        },
        invalid: {
            price: number;
            inventory: number;
            name: string;
            country: string;
            quantity: number;
        }
    };

    country: {
        countryOrigin: {
            name: string;
            symbol: string;
            hasTaxRate: boolean;
        }

    };

    constructor(price: number, partNumber: number, quantity: number, pricePerItem: number, partDescription: string, discountApplied: number) {
        this.item.price = price;
        this.item.partNumber = partNumber;
        this.item.quantity = quantity;
        this.item.pricePerItem = pricePerItem;
        this.item.partDescription = partDescription;
        this.item.discountApplied = discountApplied;
    }

    // methods
    calcPrice() {

    }

    getInoviceAmount() {

    }
}

// testing
// want to put this var inside the AddItem button and deleteItem and this new instance to the object created
// create a new object tied to that element
let invoiceItem = new Invoice(1, 3, 5, 6, "part", 1);
console.log(invoiceItem);


//  add an item
let addedItem = document.getElementById("addItem").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let table = document.getElementById("table-contents");
    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<tr id='item-info'> <th scope='row'>1</th> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='number'></td> <td><input type='number'></td> <td><input type='number'></td> <td><span></span></td></tr>");
});;

// delete item
let deleteItem = document.getElementById("deleteItem").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let row = document.getElementById("item-info");
    row.remove();
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark invoice-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="head-contents">
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col-3">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quanity</th>
                        <th scope="col">item number</th>
                        <th scope="col">Item price</th>
                        <th scope="col">total price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="table-contents">
                    <tr id="item-info">
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td><input type="number"></td>
                        <td>$<span>0.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` is not yet defined in your `Invoice` instances. Create it as the first line in the constructor:

```
constructor(/* ... */) {
  this.item = {};
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Hey, me again, so as of now i'm trying to pass in the value from the <input> tag into the item {} object. I'm having issues type casting. i've used                            
let priceVal = document.getElementsByClassName("item-price-val").value as HTMLInputElement;                                                                                                      it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @FanonX Can you post a new question and tag me in a comment? I'll check it out.